# Clone() form subclass in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, clone

I have a parent class Person which implements Cloneable interface and a subclass Student. I used two different ways to implement the clone method.

```
public class Person implements Cloneable{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    .....

    //implementation 1
    @Override public Person clone() {
        return new Person(name, age);
    }

    //implementation 2
    @Override public Person clone() {
        try {
            return (Person) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }
}

public class Student extends Person{
}
```

My question is: when I use implementation 1 and run the following code, it returns class Person. However if I use implementation 2, it returns class Student. I know it's not a convention to use constructor in clone method. But I'm really confused what is the cause of the above difference.

```
Student s = new Student();
System.out.println(s.clone().getClass());
```

Thanks in advance! And let me know if my post is duplicate.

Comment: Because Object’s clone() method works by magic. It creates an object of the same class as the object being cloned. Don’t use clone, create a copy constructor if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation 1 will never ever return anything than an empty `Person`.
Implementation 2 will eventually call the `Object.clone()` which tries to create an actual copy of the current instance it is. And right now that instance is a Student, so it tries to copy that Student and returns it.